# htaccess need to redirect the main domain but not addon domains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I know nothing about htaccess more than talking to support today and them telling me I need to use it to fix my issue.

Long story short...I have a main domain on a cPanel that is a wordpress eCommerce site. I bought and set up an SSL certificate for it. I also have 4 addon sites setup that are just plain html. The SSL doesn't work on them. (I don't know why, they said the type of ssl only works on the main site).

In the wordPress eCommerce Site, I had a plugin forcing a redirect to https version of the site. It did that by modifying the .htaccess file. BUT, it modifies it in a way that all the addon sites get redirected to https too. They then show a message saying that they are not safe and get me out of here and so on... not good!

So my question is how can a write an .htaccess file so only the main site gets redirected to an https version and not the addons?

example sites:

```
mymainsite.com -> https://mymainsite.com 
myaddonsite1.com -> no redirect
myaddonsite2.com -> no redirect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect  mainsite to https, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Just replace **mainsite.com** with your **domainname.com** in the http_host value.